# Java Closest LocalDate

Tags: java, localdate

I have a List of LocalDate objects (`dates`) and I want to find the entry in the list that is closest to a given date (`milestoneDate`).

Closest means that the date could be before or after `milestoneDate` but it has the least difference. For example something the day before `milestoneDate` would be closer than something 2 days after `milestoneDate`.

So far the best idea I have is to convert the values in `dates` toEpochSecond and then get the absolute value for the difference between that value and the `toEpochSecond` of `milestoneDate` and select the min value.

```
long milestoneSeconds = milestoneDate.atStartOfDay().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);

return dates.stream().sorted((x, y) -> {
            long xDiff = Math.abs(x.atStartOfDay().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) - milestoneSeconds);
            long yDiff = Math.abs(y.atStartOfDay().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) - milestoneSeconds);
            return (int) (xDiff - yDiff);
        }).findFirst();
```

While I suspect this will work, it feels a bit heavy. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number of days between the milestone date and each of the dates in the list directly. There is no need to convert to an epoch second.

```
dates.stream().min(Comparator.comparingLong(
    x -> Math.abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x, milestoneDate))
));
```

Note that there can be cases where there are 2 dates that are equally close to the milestone date - one before it and one after it. If you have a preference of which one to choose in this situation, you can add a `thenComparing` to the comparator:

```
// gets the date before
dates.stream().min(Comparator.<LocalDate>comparingLong(
    x -> Math.abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x, milestoneDate))
).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));

// gets the date after
dates.stream().min(Comparator.<LocalDate>comparingLong(
    x -> Math.abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(x, milestoneDate))
).thenComparing(
    Comparator.<LocalDate>naturalOrder().reversed()
));
```

It's a bit unfortunate that Java can't infer the type parameters :(

Comment: Also there can be ties. OP should address or incorporate any tie breaker rules accordingly.

Comment: @Atmas Thank you for reminding me! I usually think a lot about edge cases in dates and times, but this time I didn't think of that for some reason.

Comment: Glad I could help you out! I'm sure you would've come to it eventually.

Comment: Why sort the entire stream? `Stream` has got a `min` method that I think is just fine for the purpose.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right, that is more concise. Though I do wonder if `sorted(...).findFirst()` will be O(n) just like `min` as streams are lazily evaluated...

Comment: Curious question, I like it. It depends on which sorting algorithm the stream employs. You are probably right, it would be possible and meaningful to devise one that has good performance for getting just the first element/first few elements from the sorted order.